# how to build ios app for apple store using PWA builder

Tags: progressive-web-apps

i already have a website. I need to create a ios app on ios app store.

I tried capacitor js but still need to maintain it. I think PWA is best suited for it, but also need the app to be listed on apple app store.

for android there is bubblewrap but is there something for ios / apple ?
Ref: link to bubblewrap https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/bubblewrap